# How to automatically redirect to my website after the payment is done with parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have DOT NET application with Paypal integration. Here i want to automatically redirect to my website after the payment is done with parameter i.e Client ID. I mean How can i add parameter to RETURN URL in Paypal account. I did following code in .ASPX page for returning to my Website, it is working fine. But all clients are not clicking on return link button after payment is done, so their details are not storing in database. i want to store transaction details into database table with Client ID. Can any one have solution for this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.mysite.com/PaypalInvoice.aspx?ClientID=<%=Session["clientID_Session"]%>"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000); give some time like 1000/2000 milliseconds and in function call set the url of your required page.
and on creation of that page 
do something like this
select * from user_details where client_id= '+client_id+';
and one more thing when some one click on payment at that time make one column in your table (and set default value to 0....) and set it to 1.

when value ==1
your data should be updated in user_details and when that required page loaded it shows every updated data.

hope it will help you
i have implemented this idea for sending mail after registration..